# Using Lua "require" from inside a zip using physfs

Tags: c++, c, lua, physfs

When using physfs, loading and running a lua script is easy enough by using luaL_dostring and reading the file in myself, but when it comes to using "require", it obviously has trouble.

Has anyone dealt with this problem? Do I need to.... re-write part of lua? I'd really prefer to not do that!

Thanks.

Update, this is how I got it to work

```
static int MyLoader(lua_State *L)
{
    const char *name = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    std::string s = name;
    std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), '.', '/'); // replace all '.' to '/'
    s += ".lua"; // apend .lua
    File moduleFile = FileManager::ReadFile(s.c_str());
    if( luaL_loadbuffer(L, moduleFile.data, moduleFile.fileLength, name) ) {
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and then after creating the lua state...

```
lua_register(L, "my_loader", MyLoader);
const char* str = "table.insert(package.searchers, 2, my_loader) \n";
luaL_dostring(L, str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`package.searchers` table](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers) contains a list of loader functions for `require`.

If you want `require` to load files from a zip file, you will need to add a function that inspects the zip file. If the path exists in the zipfile, extract it to a memory buffer and call `luaL_loadbuffer` and `checkload`, like `searcher_Lua` does.